# Cloudformation Yaml Intrinsic Function Full Function Names

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-cloudformation

I wish to use Cloudformation Yaml Intrinsic Function Full Function Names.

The idea is to convert this piece of working short form notation to full form notation - but my attmpts to date have failed - any ideas would be much apprreciated :)

```
 TargetOriginId: !Join
  - ''
  - - 'S3-Website-'
    - !Select
      - 2
      - !Split
        - /
        - !GetAtt WebsiteBucket.WebsiteURL
```

Failed attempts

```
TargetOriginId:
  Fn::Join:
    - ''
    -
      - 'S3-Website-'
      - Fn::Select:
          - 2
          -
            - Fn::Split:
                - /
                -
                  - Fn::GetAtt:
                      - WebsiteBucket
                      - WebsiteURL
```

Reports error

Template error: every Fn::Join object requires two parameters, (1) a string delimiter and (2) a list of strings to be joined or a function that returns a list of strings

Also tried

```
TargetOriginId:
  - Fn::Join: ['', ['S3-Website-', Fn::Select: ['2', [Fn::Split: ['/', Fn::GetAtt: [WebsiteBucket, WebsiteURL]]]]]]
```

Reports error

Template format error: YAML not well-formed.

Answer (score 0):

Working solution

```
TargetOriginId:
  Fn::Join:
    - ''
    - - 'S3-Website-'
      - Fn::Select:
          - 2
          - Fn::Split:
              - /
              - Fn::GetAtt:
                  - WebsiteBucket
                  - WebsiteURL
```